# Order View Page not showing Customer order details?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

Recently I have faced one errors on Order View page. When I am clicking on view customer order to see the details of the customer but the order view page not showing any information of customers order.

Could you please check my screenshot which I have added here. Please give the code with file location then I can sort it out.

[image]

Thanks in Advance
Shakib

Comment: Can you check system.log and exception.log?

Comment: I have already check but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: @Shakib Rahman,Check browser console log.

Comment: Nothing is showing on Browser Console log